# How to set value in input text with choices

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have an element:

```
<input type="text" Title="test" choices="aucune|0| testA|1| testB|2|" />
```

I'd like to select value with id 2, how can I achive this?

Solution:

I found solution on this post:
When you have more than 20 items in an input select it changes to an input text linked to an hidden for selected value
http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2011/04/06/setting-sharepoint-drop-down-lists-w-jquery---20-items.aspx

Comment: You messed up spelling of `choices`

Comment: are you looking for something like this : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use select

```html
<select>
      <option value="0">aucune</option>
      <option value="1">testA</option>
      <option value="2" selected>testB</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: i'd prefer but i can't change else i wouldn't ask a question.

Comment: can't change what? Are you just attempting to get the text right before |2|?